# How much time does it take to a Microsoft Teams app get passes the certification step when publishing?

Tags: office-js, microsoft-teams, office-store

I've submitted an app 3 days ago, and it's "stuck" in the "certification" step.
Does anyone the normal waiting time for this step?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish) for more information regarding the app submission.

Answer (score 0):

It varies a bit, probably depending on the team's schedule, but it's usually within a couple of days - I'd say allow up to a week at max. You can mail the verification team directly though at teamsubm@microsoft.com if you need.